# Spring Boot - JWT authentication without db calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Is it possible to implement simple JWT authentication (not caring about invalidating tokens - I'll do it in cache) without database calls to load user into Security Context? I see my current implementation hits database with every call to api (to load user into security context). Below you can see part of implementation of **JwtAuthenticationFilter** extending **OncePerRequestFilter**:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);
            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And here is the call to database, which I would like to avoid (with every authenticated call to api):

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    // This method is used by JWTAuthenticationFilter
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : " + id)
        );
        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }
}
```

I found some kind of solution of problem to build UserPrincipal object (it implements **UserDetails** interface) with only **user id**, **username** and **granted authorities**, and without e.g. **password**, which I cannot read from JWT token itself (the rest I can), but I am not sure if it's secure and and considered as a good-practice solution (**UserDetails** class requires password field and storing it JWT would not be wise I think). I need UserPrincipal instance (implementing UserDetails interface) to support as argument to **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**, as you can see in the first paragraph.

Comment: it is better to provide a demo code repo

Comment: You have to provide more code. In the code you provided there is nowhere a database call to be seen. And that is how JWT is supposed to work. Without any call to the database. But provide more code or just like @clevertension said. And I'll try to help you

Comment: I supplied more code, tell me if you need more details. Any help I will much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be having two filter as follows.

1. **CustomAuthenticationFilter** that serves only login request/endpoint. You can do the following in this filter,

   - Call the db and validate the credential and retrieve the roles of the user
   - Generate the JWT token and you can store the user id or email along with roles in the subject of the JWT token. As we are adding user specific details I would recommend to encrypt the JWT token.
2. **CustomAuthroizationFilter** that serves all other requests/endpoints. You can do the following in this filter,

   - Validate JWT token
   - Retrieve the user id or email along with roles of the user from the subject of the JWT token.
   - Build spring authentication (**UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**) and set it in **SecurityContextHolder** like you did.

This way you will be calling db only during the login request not for all other api endpoints.